# match character by character in regex

Tags: regex

I have to validate if the word contains first letter as "A" second as "R" third as "T". I want to validate it as user is typing so want to validate it character by character. Is there a way in regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: `^(A|AR|ART|ART.+)$`. Only "A", "AR", "ART", and "ART..." are valid. Though, there's probably a shorter/better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex !

```
^(A|AR|ART.*)$
```

^ represents that the starting character should be like 'A' or 'AR' or 'ART' .The pipe '|' shows that the conditional that multiple regex are possible and '$' signs indicate the end of the line .

I test it through regex 101 & attached is the output !
[image: output]